# Data not displayed on Grid in angular 4

Tags: json, angular, api

I want to populate my grid with the data which i am receiving from API

below is my API response which i am getting

```
[
 {
   "intUserId": 1109,
   "vcrFirstName": "sdvlbs",
   "vcrLastName": "dsbvsdfn",
   "vcrLoginName": "!@#DBASDI?\"|}",
   "vcrPassword": "eclerx#123",
   "vcrStatus": "InActive",
   "vcrIsClient": "eClerx",
   "vcrEmail": "sdvlbs.dsbvsdfn@eClerx.com",
   "vcrRole": "Analyst,Auditor,Team Lead,Manager",
   "Agreements_Selected": "ISDA,CSA,Repo,SLA,PBA"
 }
]
```

But at the time of passing this data to HTML by grid is still blank

Below is my .ts code

```
arrBirds:Array<string> = [];
userdata(){
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res)=>{

this.arrBirds = Array.of(res.json()) ;
console.log(this.arrBirds)

});
}
```

Below is my HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="search_grid_view table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th style="min-width: 100px;">Login Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let char of arrBirds">

             <td >
                    {{char.vcrPassword}}
                  </td>
                  <td >
                  {{char.vcrStatus}}
                  </td>
                  <td >
                  {{char.Agreements_Selected}}
                  </td>   
                  <td >
                  {{char.vcrEmail}}
                   </td> 


        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

i am trying to iterate the data which i am receiving from API response

Below is my API code

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetCheckBoxes()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response;


        UserDB userDB = new UserDB();
        DataSet ds = userDB.UserGridDetails();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0], Formatting.Indented);

        //response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "[" + json + "]");
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);

        return response;

    }
```

my grid doesn't populate with the data.
i am struggling since last 5 days.

Comment: Are u getting  this.arrBirds??

Comment: i am getting the below output in this.arrbirds
       [
 {
   "intUserId": 1109,
   "vcrFirstName": "sdvlbs",
   "vcrLastName": "dsbvsdfn",
   "vcrLoginName": "!@#DBASDI?\"|}",
   "vcrPassword": "eclerx#123",
   "vcrStatus": "InActive",
   "vcrIsClient": "eClerx",
   "vcrEmail": "sdvlbs.dsbvsdfn@eClerx.com",
   "vcrRole": "Analyst,Auditor,Team Lead,Manager",
   "Agreements_Selected": "ISDA,CSA,Repo,SLA,PBA"
 }
]

Comment: whats the error??

Comment: there is no error, earlier i used to get the error i.e ngfor only support iterables such as array, but after converting the response of this.arrbirds to array there is no error

Comment: are you getting array from server (res)

Comment: check console.log(res)

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

I think html file is not in sync with http response

```
 <tr *ngFor="let char of arrBirds">
                 <td > {{char?.vcrPassword}}</td>
                 <td > {{char?.vcrStatus}} </td>
                 <td > {{char?.Agreements_Selected}}</td>   
                 <td > {{char?.vcrEmail}} </td> 
    </tr>
```

Change this in tr,it will work.

If it still don't work then import ChangeDetectorRef from angular/core

inject it in constructor and use detectchanges method in ChangeDetectorRef

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    userdata(){
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res)=>{

    this.arrBirds = Array.of(res.json()) ;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    console.log(this.arrBirds)

    });
    }
```

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 0):

By parsing the JSON data it is working now.

```
userdata(){
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res)=>{
this.arrBirds = JSON.parse(res.json()) as Application[];
console.log(this.arrBirds)
});

}
```